# No Such File or Directory, Global, Error with Company Mode

Tags: init-file, company-mode

I'm currently following [this guide](https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) to expanding my emacs configuration on my Mac OS X system.

However, every time I (save-buffer) with `C-x C-s`, I get the following error message:

`apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, global`

I installed GNU Global from homebrew, and have included it in my emacs path (when I print out the PATH variable, I get this in my minibuffer:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: ... /:/usr/local/Cellar/global/6.6.2_1`

As you can see, I have the GNU Global installation where in the Cellar directory, and have included this directory in my emacs path.

I'm not sure what's causing the error, or even how to fix it. Is there anything I can print out to help debug this?

Comment: How do you print the path?

Comment: Check if Emacs is able to find `global` in `PATH` by evaluating `(executable-find "global")`. You can do it simply by yanking this code into a scratch buffer and typing `C-j` with point after the expression. It should NOT return `nil`.

Comment: Okay, the lisp command returned nil. I even changed the path to `/usr/local/Cellar` and `/usr/local/Cellar/global/` but still nothing is working. I checked with `brew` and I definitely _do_ [have the GNU Global application](https://imgur.com/a/sjmypXT) 

@wvxvw I print the path with (getenv "PATH")

Comment: Okay, so I did some digging around and this was the problem:

`(executable-find [var] )` 

Doesn't look in PATH. it looks in "exec-path". 
Exec-path for me didn't have the 'usr/local/bin' directory. 
To fix this, i just did:
`(setq exec-path (cons "usr/local/bin" exec-path))` Now, I can find global with no problems!